# Providing a bijective rule for a function

Tags: functions

I am looking for a rule of association which establishes a natural bijection from $\{Y ⊆ X: x ∉ Y\}$ to $\{Y ⊆ X: x ∈ Y\}$ (where $x ∈ X$) and I would like to prove that the rule is a bijection.

Here's the rule I came up with: $X ↦ X ∪ \{x\}$

To show this is a bijection, we must show that it is both injective and surjective.

Showing that each element of the domain maps to a unique value in the codomain: Suppose there are two elements from the codomain, call them $B$ and $C$, such that $A ↦ B$ and $A ↦ C$. By the rule of association given, this would mean $A ∪ \{x\} = B$ and $A ∪ \{x\} = C$. So $B = C$.

Injective: Each element of the codomain would be mapped to by at most one element from the domain. Let $A$ be an element of the codomain and $B$, $C$ be elements of the domain such that $B ↦ A$ and $C ↦ A$. By the rule of association, $B ∪ \{x\} = A$ and $C ∪ \{x\} = A$. But then $B$ must be equal to $C$ since we are adding the same, single element to each set and as a result, they are equal.

I am pretty sure that what I have up to this point is correct (although if anyone spots any errors in the proof or the rule of association, that would be greatly appreciated). However, I am not quite sure how to prove that the rule is surjective. I was wondering if anyone can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map is, more precisely, $Y\mapsto Y\cup\{x\}$. It certainly is a map
$$
\{Y\subseteq X:x\notin X\}\to\{Y\subseteq X:x\in X\}
$$
because obviously $Y\cup\{x\}$ is a subset of $X$ and $x\in Y\cup\{x\}$.

*The map is injective.* Suppose $Y\cup\{x\}=Z\cup\{x\}$, with $x\notin Y$ and $x\notin Z$. Let $y\in Y$; then $y\in Y\cup\{x\}=Z\cup\{x\}$, so $y\in Z$ or $y=x$; the latter case cannot happen, so $y\in Z$. Hence $Y\subseteq Z$ and, by symmetry, $Z\subseteq Y$.

*The map is surjective.* Suppose $x\in Z\subseteq X$; then $x\notin Y=Z\setminus\{x\}$. Can you prove that $Y\cup\{x\}=Z$?

---

Your argument is sound up to a detail: when you say

> By the rule of association, $B ∪ \{x\} = A$ and $C ∪ \{x\} = A$. But then $B$ must be equal to $C$ since we are adding the same, single element to each set and as a result, they are equal.

you should point out that the reason for $B=C$ is that $x\notin B$ and $x\notin C$.

As an example, if $B=\{0\}$, $C=\{0,1\}$ and $x=1$, then $B\cup\{x\}=C\cup\{x\}$, but $B\ne C$. This doesn't contradict injectivity of your map, because $x\in C$, in this case.

Comment: @DiscipleOfKant That's simpler: Since $Z\setminus\{x\}\subseteq Z$ and $x\in Z$, we have $(Z\setminus\{x\})\cup\{x\}\subseteq Z$. On the other hand, if $z\in Z$, then either $z=x$ or $z\in Z\setminus\{x\}$.

Comment: I believe so. Let *y* ∈ *Y*∪ {*x*}. Then there are two cases: _y_ ∈ _Y_ or _y_ = _x_. Case 1: _y_ ∈ _Y_ . Since _Y_ = _Z_ \ {_x_} (which by definition of set difference, _y_ ∈ _Z_ \ {_x_} iff _y_ ∈ _Z_ and _y_ ∉ {_x_}), and we know by supposition that _y_ is not equal to _x_, then _y_ is an element of _Z_. Case 2: _y_ ∈ {_x_}. Then _y_ = _x_ and we know _x_ ∈ _Z_ by the principal supposition. Therefore _y_ ∈ _Z_. In either case, _y_ ∈ _Z_; therefore _Y_ = _Z_ \ {_x_} ⊆ _Z_. On the other hand, suppose _y_ ∈ _Z_. We know that _Y_ = _Z_ \ {_x_}, so every element in _Z_ is in _Y_, except for _x_.

Comment: My apologies, my comments keep getting deleted for some reason. Thank you for your comments, they were very helpful. That is much simpler.